# Find out what a Wordpress template function does

Tags: wordpress, function, templates

I'm trying to get a deeper understanding of how Wordpress works. Let's say I find this function in a Wordpress Template file:

`wp_do_something()`

What's the best/easiest way to find out what it does?

Thanks in advance!
/ WP Newbie

Answer (score 1):

When you find a wordpress function you can do either of the two [most time i do the second one]

- You can search google to find the definition of function, it's parameters, and the exact use of that function. So you can make use of [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/) and [developer](https://developer.wordpress.org/) sites of WordPress.
- Or you could use a text editor like Sublime text to search the function inside wordpress directory so that you could find what exactly a function does. This way you won't be wrong.